# Are there some features of redux not provided on react?

Tags: reactjs, api, redux

I need to start building a data management app, with some CMS like features. The backend is built on Node and frontend needs to work with its API with react.

By using hooks like `useReducer` and `useContext`, I can see the core functionality of redux implemented in React core itself.

**Are there some functionalities of redux I might miss out on if I choose to not use them at all?**

Comment: `useReducer` is still local to the component.  It isn't app-wide like Redux.  You can always add Redux later.

Comment: Hooks didn't add these features, it just added a new way to use them. Context and state already existed before.

Comment: But useContext allows it to go app-wide right?

Comment: Context was always available.

Answer (score 1):

While `useReducer` sounds like it will behave like Redux does, it is an entirely different concept (well not entirely, but it isn't global), so for the time being just ignore it.

Internally, Redux uses contexts to inject data into components without passing it through the whole tree, so theoretically you could do everything that redux can do with `useContext`, but you would need tons of your own custom code.

Personally, I think that people are far to quick to jump to using Redux to solve simple tasks. If you have state that isn't often updated, or only updated from a single component high up in the tree, you could easily get away with using a context to deliver the data to deeper components which then access the context through `useContext`.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing still not in React Hook is in the aspect of useContext is the functionality provided by Redux middleware. In short, if you have a complex app and need to make a series of API calls and those call may have race condition, async/sync mix up together and other complicated situation, you need the help of middleware like saga for manage those API calls in the order / way you want. React Context API still not be able to handle situation like this.